# Class loading constraint violated in WAS 8.5

Tags: websphere, classloader

I am trying to deploy a web service on WAS 8.5 and i am getting the following exception in the server log while starting the application. This service was running on WAS 7 previously.

I had changed the class loading config to parent last and tested but had no luck.
I have jersey-server 1.9.1 in my assembly.

Does anyone have any idea about this ?

Thanks in advance.

[3/7/14 6:42:30:854 CST] 00000067 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\websphere\appserver\profiles\appsrv01\logs\ffdc\HDATA_eaodr01_28fb9514_14.03.07_06.42.30.8542488091000782805797.txt com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl 297
[3/7/14 6:42:30:854 CST] 00000001 ContainerHelp E   WSVR0501E: Error creating component com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl@76c05e49
com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: **com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=com/sun/jersey/server/impl/container/servlet/JerseyServletContainerInitializer, method=onStartup(Ljava/util/Set;Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)V, pc=0**
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:432)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1173)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:772)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2175)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:994)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:496)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1815)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=com/sun/jersey/server/impl/container/servlet/JerseyServletContainerInitializer, method=onStartup(Ljava/util/Set;Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)V, pc=0
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:759)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=com/sun/jersey/server/impl/container/servlet/JerseyServletContainerInitializer, method=onStartup(Ljava/util/Set;Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)V, pc=0
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:176)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=com/sun/jersey/server/impl/container/servlet/JerseyServletContainerInitializer, method=onStartup(Ljava/util/Set;Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)V, pc=0
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:93)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:170)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1564)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$ServiceIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:216)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebAppImpl.java:535)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:409)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
    ... 17 more

Comment: Please tell me you found a solution for this!

Comment: Hi, can you share the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This technote might help you:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1011249

Comment: Please do include the relevant elements of the referenced link into your answer. Answers containing just a link and "this could help" are not deemed a good fit for StackOverflow. Please also see [this meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231)